# go-zookeeper Connect returns without a valid connection

Tags: go, apache-zookeeper

I have a question regarding zookeeper, I am trying to implement simple service discovery with zookeeper in go, I am using go-zookeeper: https://github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper

My question is whenever I connect to zookeeper using for example:

```
zoo_keeper, _, err := zk.Connect(s, time.Second)
```

the function returns immediately and no error is reported, but there is no actual valid connection yet. Now for example if I want to create znodes, what do I need to check to make sure I have a valid connection before doing so?

Comment: Did you check if `err != nil`. There can be an error occurred.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha Yes I have checked it and there is no error. Now I assume that connect just return a connection object which might be not connected. Similar to the zookeeper constructor in the java API. But I am not sure if my assumptions are right.

Comment: Ahh... yes. The constructor returns immediately. You have to add a Watcher and check for  the synConnected event

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha I am new to both go and zookeeper, if you have an example code, it would be great.
The go-zookeeper documentation does not clarify much. I have found this function func WithEventCallback(cb EventCallback) connOption
I assume this is what you mean but not sure how to use it.

Comment: I couldn't find a proper example, but if you use [this](https://github.com/flier/curator.go) go client, you can use [this](https://github.com/flier/curator.go/blob/master/client.go#L128) constructor to  achieve what you need.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha Thank for the link. It seems like they are also using go-zookeeper as well. I will try to dif into the code to understand how things are implemented. In the meanwhile I figured out how to do what I wanted using channels. I will post the code as answer, maybe to help someone else who had the same issue.

Comment: Yes, but they are providing more high level functionalities like apache-curator for zookeeper. All you have to do is registering a watcher. Then check for the events being received

Comment: I am trying to learn the basics of zookeeper, so this is why I try to implement this with as low primitives as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying several things, and thanks to the suggestion from Imesha, I can achieve what I wanted using channels. Below is my sample code.

```
func zk_connect(zk_server string) (*zk.Conn, error) {
    zoo_keeper, session, err := zk.Connect([]string{zk_server}, time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for event := range session {
        if event.State == zk.StateConnected {
            log.Printf("zookeeper State: %s\n", event.State)
            break
        }
    }
    return zoo_keeper, nil
}
```